# Naive Bayes classifier :Number of dataset samples problems

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, naivebayes

I have been working upon a text classification problem. I am using a naive bayes text classifier as shown [here](https://medium.com/@equipintelligence/bayes-text-classification-machine-learning-algorithms-915d320abcdb).

The text is being classified into CLASS1 and CLASS2. I am using a dataset of 18 samples. From that , 3 samples belong to CLASS1 and 18 belong to CLASS2.

The problem is that when no words of both the classes are detected then the expected output should be NOTIDENTIFIED.

In practice it gives the output as CLASS2 as the class probability is greater than CLASS1 because of the difference in their size of sample dataset.

What could I do to have the output as NOTIDENTIFIED ?

Comment: You need to include examples for the third class NOTIDENTIFIED as well. It sees only two classes present and is forced to choose one  among the two. Thus extend your dataset with more examples that belong to neither CLASS1 or CLASS2. (Also try to increase the size of your dataset and make the number of samples in each class nearly equal)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sruthi. I will make sure to add equal number of samples of each class in the dataset.